# Checkbox box loses its class using AngularJS and Material Design Lite Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I try to do a table with filter, but when I use filter in a table that uses the class mdl-data-table--selectable the checkbox disappears or loses its style.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col-desktop" ng-controller="alumnosCtrl" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:600px;">
    <h4>Alumnos que actualizaron sus datos</h4>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" ng-model="searchStudent" ng-text-change="">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2">Ingrese cualquier caracteristica</label>
    </div>
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col-desktop ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Nombre</th>
                <th  class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Apellidos</th>
                <th>Celular</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchStudent">
                <td >{{student.DNI}}</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{student.Nombre}}</td>
                <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{student.ApePat + student.ApeMat}}</td>
                <td>{{student.TelefonoCelular}}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I do to fix that?

This is an example where I have that problem: [AngularJS MDL Problem Here](http://codepen.io/victorcobden/pen/jryBZW)

Comment: how the checkbox is getting rendered you dont have it in ur dom and neither u r using any directive

Comment: Hi, the framework(MDL) does it automatically.

Comment: Since the checkboxes are rendered through the framework, you would need to use pure angular based solution instead of using framework, you can rely on the framework for styling purpose.